# tensorflow basic word2vec example: Shouldn't we be using weights [nce_weight Transpose] for the representation and not embedding matrix?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, word2vec

I am referreing to [this sample code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py)
in the code snippet below:

```
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_inputs)

# Construct the variables for the NCE loss
nce_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
nce_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))

loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.nce_loss(weights=nce_weights,
    biases=nce_biases,
    labels=train_labels,
    inputs=embed,
    num_sampled=num_sampled,
    num_classes=vocabulary_size))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)
```

Now NCE_Loss function is nothing but a single hidden layer neural network with softmax at the optput layer [knowing is takes only a few negative sample]

This part of the graph will only update the weights of the network, it is not doing anything to the "embeddings" matrix/ tensor.

so ideally once the network is trained we must again pass it once through the embeddings_matrix first and then multiply by the transpose of the "nce_weights" [considering it as the same weight auto-encoder, at input & output layers] to reach to the hidden layer representation of each word, which we are are calling word2vec (?)

But if look at the later part of the code, the value of the `embeddings` matrix is being used a word representation. [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py#L250)

Even the [tensorflow doc for NCE loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/nce_loss), mentions input (to which we are passing `embed`, which uses `embeddings`) as just the 1st layer input activation values.

```
inputs: A Tensor of shape [batch_size, dim]. The forward activations of the input network.
```

A normal back propagation stops at the first layer of the network, 
does this implementation of NCE loss, goes beyond and propagates the loss to the input values (and hence to the embedding) ?

This seems an extra step?
[Refer this](http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/) for why I am calling it an extra step, he has a same explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Want I have figured out reading and going through tensorflow is that

though the entire thing is single hidden layer neural network, a auto-encoder indeed. But the weights are not tied, which I assumed.

The encoder is made of the weight matrix `embeddings` and the decoder is made of the `nce_weights`. And now `embed` is nothing but the hidden layer output, given by multiplying input with `embeddings`.

So with this, `embeddings` and `nce_weights` both will be updated in the graph. And we can choose any of the two weight matrix, `embeddings` is more preferred here.

**Edit1:**

Actually for both `tf.nn.nce_loss` and `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss`, the parameters, weights and bias are for the input `Weights(tranpose) X + bias`, to objective function, which can be logistic regression/ softmax function [[refer]](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec).

But the back-propagation/ gradient descent happens till the very base of the graph you are building and does not stop at the weights and bias of the function only. Hence the `input` parameter in both  `tf.nn.nce_loss` and `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss` are also updated which in-turn is build of `embeddings` matrix.